# How can I process data to avoid MySQL "incorrect string value" error?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to use a Rake task to migrate some legacy data from MS Access to MySQL. I'm working on Windows XP, using Ruby 1.8.6.

I have the encoding for Rails set as "utf8" in `database.yml`.

Also, the default character set for MySQL is utf8.

99% of the data is coming in fine, but every now and then I'll get a column value that gives me a error something like this:

```
Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\x92 Comm...' for column 'name' 
  at row 1: 
  INSERT INTO `organizations` ( [...] ) 
  VALUES('Lawyers’ Committee', [...] )
```

It looks as though the thing that's giving MySQL trouble is the apostrophe immediately after the "s" in the word "Lawyers".

Here's another one...

```
Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\x99 aoc' for column 'department' 
  at row 1: 
  INSERT INTO `addresses` 
[...]
  'TRInfo™ aoc'
[....]
```

Looks like it's choking on the "TM" after "TRInfo".

Is there any Ruby or Rails method that I can run the data through to cleanse from it any characters that MySQL will choke on?

Ideally, it would be great to replace them with more palatable characters -- replace the apostrophe with a single quote and the TM symbol with the string "(TM)".

Or, if I could somehow configure MySQL to store those characters as-is without errors that would be great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your input data is not in utf-8.

I did a little investigating and the styled quote used in Lawyer's is encoded as \x92 in the Windows-1252 encoding, but would be nonsense for utf-8 (when I decoded it and encoded it into utf8, I got \xe2\x80\x99).

Thus you will need to convert the input strings from windows-1252 to utf-8 (or to unicode).

Comment: This solution does not answer the OP question "Is there any method..."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when putting contents of UTF-16 encoded files - which usually store one character per 16bit block - into mysql tables with java. The problem was that the UTF-16 encoded string contained so called *surrogate pairs*. It means two consecutive 16bit UTF-16 blocks encode one special character but cannot be translated into a corresponding UTF-8 encoding individually. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2) for further explanation.

The solution was to simply replace these characters with spaces. This is the character range you might want to strip out of your string: U+D800–U+DFFF

Answer (score 1):

In general, this happens when you insert strings to columns with incompatible encoding/collation.

I got this error when I had TRIGGERs, which inherit server's collation for some reason. 
And mysql's default is (at least on Ubuntu) latin-1 with swedish collation.
Even though I had database and all tables set to UTF-8, I had yet to set `my.cnf`:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf :

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
```

And this must list all triggers with utf8-*:

```
select TRIGGER_SCHEMA, TRIGGER_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, COLLATION_CONNECTION, DATABASE_COLLATION from information_schema.TRIGGERS
```

And some of variables listed by this should also have utf-8-* (no latin-1 or other encoding):

```
show variables like 'char%';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your old database is in one string format (utf8?) and your rails is expecting something else. If you input is in utf8, have you tried [configuring your rails to support it?](http://blog.dotkam.com/2008/09/14/configure-rails-and-mysql-to-support-utf-8/)

Comment: Thanks, everything is set to utf8.

Answer (score 0):

```
I encountered the same problem today.
After tried many times, I found out the reason and fix it at last.
For applications that store data using the default MySQL character set and collation (latin1, latin1_swedish_ci), so you need to specify the character set and collation to utf8/utf8_general_ci when your create your database or table.
e.g.:
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        bookname varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        author varchar(64) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id),
        KEY (bookname)
        )CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";

Reference:
《mysql create table problem? SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!!》
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?121,193883,193883
《10.1.5. Configuring the Character Set and Collation for Applications》
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

Hoping this can help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding binary before the weirdcolumn solves the problem.

In my case, I have an update trigger on tableA to insert data into other table. 
There are some special characters in column weirdcolumn, and the update failed with message: "ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE7....'"

After I dig in a lot, I found the solution by adding binary before the string column name, or using cast(weirdcolumn as binary);

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue importing data from SQL Server to MySql using Php.
My solution was `utf8_encode()` when inserting into MySql and use `utf8_decode()` when retrieving from MySql to display into the browser.
Here you have my FULL code, that works good.

```
//For string values
$Gro2=(is_null($row["GrpNm"]))?"NULL":"\"".mysql_escape_string(utf8_encode($row["GrpNm"]))."\"";


$sqlMy ="INSERT INTO `tbl_name` VALUES ($Gro2)";
```

Please note: For new projects use

```
mysqli_escape_string()
```

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)