# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x98\xBA.\x0D\x0A...'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use rails 2.3.11 and on my prod machine I got this exception. In my dev machine It worked fine, Bascially Iam submitting a textarea with huge content and the column 'message' in my db is of type text, so typicaly there shouldn't be any trouble.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value:
'\xE2\x98\xBA.\x0D\x0A...' for column 'message' at row 1: INSERT INTO `table_xyz
```

Comment: are you using same database for development and production ???check your production database???also provide your code written for the same..

Comment: Which character set / encoding is this supposed to be? If you have specified utf8 then this is being rejected because it is an invalid utf8 sequence.

Comment: This [answer][1] should help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947975/how-can-i-process-data-to-avoid-mysql-incorrect-string-value-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen (too many times) when one of the databases/tables is correctly configured to use utf8, and the other is using a different charset/collation, like latin. When the utf8 database was populated, it was done by copying over the data from the latin database. Subsequent updates/entries into the utf8 database would fail, when the data contained unicode characters, like ☃. It may be that, even without data copying, an incorrect database charset/collation could cause this. It can also sometimes help to ensure that your database yml contains `encoding: utf8`.