# How to encode and load a csv file (with \xF3n expression) to get utf-8 encoded data?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, encoding, utf-8

So I have a CSV file that contains non UTF-8 text and I want to load data to a table n my database, for that I use:

```
$con->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE bdi_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';");
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF3n'
```

My table and database have UTF-8 charset and the CSV file is non UTF-8 (in Notepad++ shows ANSI as encoding).

EDIT: Thanks to @Fred -ii- by his comment: open the CSV file and use "convert to UTF-8" (Notepad++ Encoding)

Comment: What is the charset of your file?

Comment: Try escaping it with `BY '\\n'`. or `BY '\"\n\"';` the latter I'm not 100% sure of though.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yeah I didn't notice that (I'll edit that part), but the error is another....

Comment: Your input data may not be utf-8. You will need to convert the input strings from windows-1252 to utf-8 (or to unicode), as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/948332/

Comment: Save the file as UTF-8 in Notepad++ / under "Encoding", then "convert to..." for a quick test.

Comment: Have a look at [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) there's even a comment in there directly related to your situatoin. :)

Comment: @Fred -ii- I tried "convert to..." to get UTF-8 and it lets me handle as UTF-8 and everything nice, just is there a way to don't make it manually?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy using mb_convert_encoding you mean I need to buffer the data and then create insert statements, rigth? (is there a way to use LOAD DATA? in order to make it kind of directly)

Comment: Try adding `CHARACTER SET UTF8` to your code. I.e.: `("LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE bdi_csv FIELDS CHARACTER SET UTF8 TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';")`

Comment: @Fred -ii- I've tried copying that line but not recognizes that sintax, I guess that would be if the problem is in DB. But as I've tried with "convert to...", so DB is managing rigth the data from the UTF8 file but I mean how get it from the file non-UTF8 or how to make php change it (just asking if there's another way I like the "convert to ..." way)

Comment: That I couldn't say for sure on how to do it Charles. Let's see if `Ohgodwhy` knows something more, or somebody else. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/4957900/ might be something in there.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Don't worry thank you for all, just pointing the rigth sintax `("LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' INTO TABLE bdi_csv CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';")` (the previos syntax error cause the order of CHARSET, however as I wrote my principal problem is with the CSV file)

Comment: I was close! So it worked out then, great. Thanks for the update, *cheers*